# Swiper Carousel: How to give different properties to the same carousel for different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swiper.js

I'm trying to create a carousel that has a 4x1 layout in desktop and a 2x2 layout in mobile.

This is the code but it just breaks the carousel for me.

```
  var swiper1;
$(window).resize(function() {
    var ww = $(window).width();

    if (ww <= 767) {
        swiper1 = new Swiper('#swiper2', {

                slidesPerView: 2,
                slidesPerColumn: 2,
                spaceBetween: 10
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        swiper1 = new Swiper('#swiper2', {

                slidesPerView: 4,
                slidesPerColumn: 1,
                spaceBetween: 30
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Originally the code used to be just simply this:

```
var swiper1 = new Swiper('#swiper2', {
                slidesPerView: 4,
                slidesPerColumn: 1,
                spaceBetween: 30
});
```

This is what was working for me but I would like it to change to 2x2 when the resolution is <= 767

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to destroy your old instance of Swiper before you create a new one. In the [Swiper API Docs](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/#.VZcTaPlVhBc), the Methods section has info on the destroy method for Swiper. In your case you would want to call it like this: `swiper1.destroy(true, true);`.

Your updated javascript could look like this:

```
   $(function () {
        createSwiper();

        $(window).resize(function () {
            createSwiper()
        });
    });

    function createSwiper() {
        var swiper1 = $('#swiper2')[0].swiper;
        if (typeof swiper1 !== 'undefined') 
            swiper1.destroy(true, true); //if swiper exists, destroy it so we can create a new one 

        var ww = $(window).width();
        if (ww <= 767) {
            swiper1 = new Swiper('#swiper2', {
                slidesPerView: 2,
                slidesPerColumn: 2,
                spaceBetween: 10
            });
        } else {
            swiper1 = new Swiper('#swiper2', {
                slidesPerView: 4,
                slidesPerColumn: 1,
                spaceBetween: 30
            });
        }
    }
```

I put the create swiper logic in its own function and call it on page load and attach it to the window resize event.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ecm8kw3/1/) so you can see it in action (resize the frame window).

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs you can now use breakpoints to provide different parameters for different screen size. As the [Swiper Docs](https://swiperjs.com/api/) has no anchors, search for "Breakpoints" in "Swiper Parameters" section.

In your case it is:

```
  var swiper1 = new Swiper('#swiper2', {
    slidesPerView: 2,
    slidesPerColumn: 2,
    spaceBetween: 10
    // ...
    breakpoints: {
      // when window width is >= 767px
      767: {
         slidesPerView: 4,
         slidesPerColumn: 1,
         spaceBetween: 30,
      }
    }
  });
```

**Note**: The docs reads that inside the breakpoints you can use only a part of the parameters, that do not change the carousel behaviour too dramatically.